# BloomBerg API - It is possible to get the top 200 Securities?

Tags: bloomberg

I'm currently doing a feeder and i'm using Bloomberg API but I only need to get the top 200 securities for a specific period, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Top 200 securities based on what criteria? In what universe? etc.

Comment: Hi, any criteria or group.. i just wanted to know if it's possible in bloomberg api. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do a securities search through the API. If you have a well defined universe (say 1000 stocks and want the top 200 based on performance for the day), you can always query the performance for the day field for the 1000 stocks and sort/filter in your application.

ps: I assume you are talking about the [open blp api](http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's possible since I know it can be done via the Excel API. Use the EQS in the Bloomberg Terminal to create a screen. There, choose the equity universe and the sort criteria. You can now download to Excel the equities which the screen displays. I recommend you ask the Help Desk (F1 F1 on the Terminal) how to download an EQS screen via API v3.